# Why won't this CSV print out correctly? (Magento Categories)

Tags: php, csv, magento

I have a script that is meant to output Magento categories' data to a CSV file:

```html
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$categoryId = 228;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$outputFile = "var/export/categories-and-ids.csv";
$write = fopen($outputFile, 'w');

echo '<pre>';

function writeoutcategory($parent)
{
  $_categories = $parent->getChildrenCategories();
  foreach($_categories as $cat)
  {
    $data = [/*
      '"'.trim($cat->getName()).'"',
      '"'.$cat->getId().'"',
      '"'.trim($cat->getParentCategory()->getName()).'"',
      '"'.$cat->getParentCategory()->getId().'"',*/
      trim($cat->getName()),
      $cat->getId(),
      trim($cat->getParentCategory()->getName()),
      $cat->getParentCategory()->getId(),
    ];
    print_r($data); echo '<br>';
    fputcsv($write, $data);

    if(count($cat->getChildrenCategories())) writeoutcategory($cat);
  }
}

writeoutcategory($category);

echo '</pre>';

fclose($write);

echo "File written at ".$outputFile;
```

Before and I don't know why then and not now it was printing fine, just every row was all in one column separated by commas.

Now it comes out just a bunch of jarbled symbols (in OpenOffice Calc). When "Filter Selection" comes up prior to opening the file, I choose Text CSV, then UTF-8 encoding, then it opens this up in OpenOffice Writer (?):

> ��#ࡱ#�################;###��  #############################����####����########�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������R#o#o#t#
>
> ## E#n#t#r#y#################################################������������####################################����############################################################################������������####################################����############################################################################������������####################################����############################################################################������������####################################����

What am I doing wrong, please?

This makes no sense. Updated the file to:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$categoryId = 228; // PTL > Tablecloths
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

echo '<pre>';

$rows = [];

function collectCategories($parent)
{
  $_categories = $parent->getChildrenCategories();
  foreach($_categories as $cat)
  {
    $data = [
      trim($cat->getName()),
      $cat->getId(),
      trim($cat->getParentCategory()->getName()),
      $cat->getParentCategory()->getId(),
    ];
    var_dump($data);
    $rows[] = $data;

    if(count($cat->getChildrenCategories())) collectCategories($cat);
  }
}

collectCategories($category);

echo '</pre>';

$outputFile = "var/export/categories-and-ids.csv";
$write = fopen($outputFile, 'w');
foreach($rows as $row) fputcsv($write, $row);
fclose($write);
echo "File written at ".$outputFile;
```

It still opens the above in OO Calc and blank in Notepad. What could possibly be wrong?

UPDATE: Now I've simply appended the file with this:

```
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('var/export/file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Which outputs this (Atom):

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd 
123,456,789 
"""aaa""","""bbb"""
```

This in OO Calc:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd
123456789
"aaa","""bbb"""
```

(one column)

and my categories-and-ids.csv is still blank and won't open as CSV through OO.

Comment: At first glance I don't see anything wrong with your code. It looks to be some encoding problem or a problem with OpenOffice. What happens if you open your file in a text editor instead of OpenOffice? And if you replace `print_r($data); echo '<br>';` with `implode(',' $data) . "\n"; does it look right? And if you replace the `print_r` with `var_dump`, are all contents of the type `(str)`? What encoding have you set on your server?

Comment: Not sure of the encoding. If I open it in Notepad it's straight blank. var_dump does show strings.

Comment: I added 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); to the top and it still opens blank in Notepad. What can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

OH wow the function wasn't returning anything obviously it wasn't adding to $rows as $rows was initialized outside of it. I'm an idiot.

Comment: So am I for not seeing this obvious mistake :-) Those are the hardest!